# how to create a moving image

Tags: ios, uiimageview

How do I create an image which moves into the screen?
So it comes up from the bottom and stops when totally visible. I would also play with the speed and direction. It's not like scrolling of photos as demonstrated in the PhotosSroller example of Apple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CGRect endFrame = [[self view] frame];
[imageView setFrame: CGRectMake([[self view] frame].origin.x, [[self view] frame].origin.y + 480.0, [[self view] frame].size.width, [[self view] frame].size.height)];
[UIView beginAnimations: nil context: NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.25];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[imageView setFrame: endFrame];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

It's not tested but that will give you an idea.

### Update:

For the sake of animation block

```
[imageView setFrame: CGRectMake([[self view] frame].origin.x, [[self view] frame].origin.y + 480.0, [[self view] frame].size.width, [[self view] frame].size.height)];

[UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0f animations: ^{
[imageView setCenter: [[self view] center]];
} ];
```

You can hide the imageView by reversing it.

(y)0 - imageView height = top
(x)0 - imageView width = left
[self view] height = bottom
[self view] width = right

Again not tested but will give you an idea how to use it.

Comment: Does this work in a UIViewController ? I used this functionality behind a button.

Comment: Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4 and later. Use the block-based animation methods instead.

Comment: It's working, I didn't initialize the UIImageView in the correct way. Probably path to figure was wrong. Thanks.

Comment: any tips for moving this image away again ?

Comment: @Erik B discouraged yes but not illegal. Apple wants developers to use newer APIs that's why the old one is discouraged. @ErikS I updated my answer. That the basic thing to hide the imageView. You can also `setHidden: YES` after the imageView left the view.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to achieve, you should be able to get the result you're looking for with `UIView` animations by animating properties such as the location, and alpha of your image view. For example, if you had a view which started out fully transparent that you wanted to move to the center of your view controllers view, you might do something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.25 animations: ^{  
    imageView.center = self.view.center;  
    imageView.alpha = 1.0f;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at `UIView`'s `animateWithDuration:` methods. You basically change the frame and that method will animate the moving of the view. It's really simple, just read the documentation. If you need any help don't hesitate to ask.