# UIImageView bounce forth and back

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, cgpoint

I've got a UIImage that when I click it, I want it to move 2px in X direction and 2px in Y direction, and then move back to the original position. So that it can be pressed multiple times, and just jiggle.

What I've got so far is this;

```
imageViewTwo.center = CGPointMake(imageViewTwo.center.x +2, imageViewTwo.center.y +2);
```

This makes the image move 2px each direction.

I tried this;

```
imageViewTwo.center = CGPointMake(imageViewTwo.center.x +2, imageViewTwo.center.y +2);
imageViewTwo.center = CGPointMake(imageViewTwo.center.x -2, imageViewTwo.center.y -2);
```

but that only made the image not move at all. These lines are in the viewDidLoad.

What I need is to make it go back right after it's been clicked to the original position.

Comment: I'm guessing that your second code is just being executed so fast that it isn't showing up on the screen. Have you considered using one of the Animation oriented classes to perform this 'jiggle'? Check out this question, it shows how to use animation, different movements, but you can adjust the coordinates. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145337/how-to-create-a-moving-image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using animation

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^
     {
         //move right
         imageViewTwo.center = CGPointMake(imageViewTwo.center.x +2, imageViewTwo.center.y +2);
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL completed)
     {
         if (completed)
         {
             //completed move right..now move left
             [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              animations:^
              {
                  imageViewTwo.center = CGPointMake(imageViewTwo.center.x -2, imageViewTwo.center.y -2);
              }];
         }
     }];
```

Comment: If it worked, make sure to up-vote and mark as correct answer.  People that reply spend their own time helping others out.